# How to get discord bot (python) to reply with a riddles answer instead of sending it in the same embed

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def Riddle(ctx):
  response = requests.get("https://ibk-riddles-api.herokuapp.com/")

  json_data = json.loads(response.text)

  Question = json_data["question"]
  Answer = "||" + json_data["answer"] + "||"

  embed =   discord.Embed(
      title = "RIDDLE",
      color = 0x00FFFF
  )
  embed.set_footer(text = "My prefix is '+'. All my commands are case insensitive.")
  embed.add_field(name = "Question",value = Question, inline = "false" )
  embed.add_field(name = "Answer",value = Answer, inline = "false" )
  await ctx.reply(embed= embed)
```

What I want is instead of the discord bot sending the riddle's answer in the same embed,I want it to send the answer in a different embed when someone replies to the bot's already sent embed which contains the question with the message "+Answer" or "+answer". I tried it in different ways but it didn't work, so here is the original code of the command, if someone can help me, please do.

Comment: Before adding a new "Answer" field, you can send the first embed, after that you can create a new embed with the "Answer" field and send it. The question and answer will be part of different embeds then.

Comment: @Billy  Yeah I did that, but is it possible for the second embed to only be sent when the user requests for it by replying to the original embed with "+Answer" or "+answer" in this case?

Comment: you can use the  [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) to wait for a reply from the user, and then match it with "answer". If the reply matches successfully, you can trigger the function which sends answer embed. There is a good example in the link provided above on doing this.